# How can I start a transition for element b when element a is hovered?

Tags: css, css-transitions, transition

I have two elements. When I hover over one of them (an img), I want it to *start a transition* on a different element on the page. I am 99.999% sure I have done this before, but I can't remember how, and no amount of searching has given me any hints.

How can I start a transition for element **b** when element **a** is hovered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `+` sibling selector.

Target element `a` for the `:hover` pseudo-class and select the sibling element `b`. Use the `transition` property on the element `b` being targeted.

```css
.a:hover + .b {
  background: #8AACFF;
}
.b {
  background: lightblue;
  transition: all ease 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">Hover over me</div>
<div class="b">My background will change</div>
```

Comment: Ok, I should have included some code. This code isn't working for me. I have two divs absolutely positioned - top to bottom then I have an image (absolute position) on top of those divs. I think the absolute position ruins this code. Is there anyway around that?

Comment: Thank you so much @Manoj! It works perfectly. I've been banging my head for hours over this.

Comment: Glad it helped! :) Next time please post your code so that we can answer quicker and better :D

Answer (score 1):

You can do so in CSS, if the second element is a sibling of the first.

Take for example the following markup:

```
<img src="…" class="hover-trigger">
<section class="hover-target">
```

and this CSS:

```
.hover-target {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 200ms linear;
}

.hover-trigger:hover + .hover-target {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

When you hover over the `img.hover-trigger` the transition on the `.hover-target` will get triggered.